# how to set matrix row header name and column header name?

Tags: r

I have a matrix that looks like the following:

```
> m <- cbind( c(1, 0), c(1, 1) )
> rownames(m) <- c('ON', 'OFF')
> colnames(m) <- c('ON', 'OFF')
> m

    ON OFF
ON   1   1
OFF  0   1
```

How can I provide a header name for the rows and columns?  E.g.

```
                  thermostat
                  ON OFF
motion_sensor ON   1   1
              OFF  0   1
```

I had a look at `?dimnames` but couldn't see/understand how to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with `names`.  `dimnames` is a `list`.  In your example, there were no names for the `list` elements, which can be assigned using `names`

```
 names(dimnames(m)) <- c('motion_sensor', 'thermostat')
 m
 #            thermostat
 #motion_sensor ON OFF
 #         ON   1   1
 #         OFF  0   1
```